# Помогите составить верно запрос

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Необходимо обновить значение Answer где idLog max мой код  не работает. Заранее спасибо!!!

```
UPDATE log_sms SET Answer= ? where (SELECT MAX(idLog) FROM log_sms order by Answer desc limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Результат подзапроса в `WHERE` надо с чем-то сравнивать. В данном случае - с `idLog`

Также из-за того, что обновляется та же таблица, по которой идёт подзапрос, придётся использовать промежуточный результат

Итоговый вариант:

```
UPDATE log_sms
SET Answer = ?
WHERE idLog = (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(idLog) FROM log_sms) as t)
```

---

Есть вариант без подзапросов (например, в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12242514/3432401)):

```
UPDATE log_sms
SET Answer = ?
ORDER BY idLog DESC
LIMIT 1
```